# How to specify file type returning file from flask?

Tags: python, http, flask, http-headers

I an building a flask function that sends the file to user for download, and deletes the file quickly after it's sent. I have managed to do so with a generator. However, in testing, the file sent the user is in a complete different format(download.htm) than the original file(.res). How to specify the file type to stay in `.res`?

Here's what I have:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download_file():

    file_pathres = dirname(realpath(__file__)) + '/' + pathres
    file_pathtxt = dirname(realpath(__file__)) + '/' + pathtxt

    print('download file path: ' + file_pathres)
    #file_path = derive_filepath_from_filename(filename)
    file_handle = open(file_pathres, 'r')

        # This *replaces* the `remove_file` + @after_this_request code above
    def stream_and_remove_file():
        yield from file_handle
        file_handle.close()
        os.remove(file_pathres)
        os.remove(file_pathtxt)

    return current_app.response_class(
        stream_and_remove_file(),
        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'}
    )
```

What should I change in the headers or the return statement ensure the send is in the same format as the file originally opened and deleted?

Comment: What is the file type that you want to send back? Will you accept more than just `.res` files? If so, what is the rule that tells you, given the file *extension*, what the file *type* is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to send back `.res` files, while `.txt` files might be ok, but ideally `.res` is what I need. The reason is that for the project I am working, we must have the files in .res otherwise it won't work with a pre-existing system. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, but what does ".res file" **mean**? Is it really only a problem with the file **name**, or is there a problem with the MIME type?

Answer (score 1):

The actual filename never gets sent to the client by default. A [filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) is an identifier that comes from the OS and not some property of the file itself. It's like a name for the pointer that points to the location on the memory or drive where the contents of that file are stored. When you send a file over the net you're sending only its contents, the raw data, along with some information header. There you could specify a directive for the client to set the filename on its filesystem if you want to (as explained further below).

If not otherwise specified, the browser just uses the endpoint of the request (`/download`) and some header information like the `media-type` (or [`MIME-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)) parameter from the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header of the response to come up with an appropriate filename. In Flask the default `Response` class is setting the `MIME-Type` of every response to `text/html` if not otherwise specified ([source](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/eb865f8c24572065a4f1c7ec8316e0d9d0eab381/src/flask/wrappers.py#L111)).

So in your case the browser takes the endpoint `/download` as the filename and chooses the extension according to the `MIME-Type`, which is `text/html` => `donwload.html`

You can either subclass the `Response` class and customize the default behaviour, which would affect all of your responses or you can set the filename (along with the extension) that should be displayed in the browsers 'Save as' dialog with the `filename` parameter in the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header of each response:

```py
return app.response_class(
  stream_and_remove_file(),
  headers={'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=testfile.res"}
)
```

The `attachment` property just tells the browser to download the contents of the response as a file and not to try to render them.

Answer (score -1):

Found a work around:

```
    r = current_app.response_class(stream_and_remove_file(), mimetype='text')
    r.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="filename.res")
    return r
```

Specify the file type in the filename parameter when setting headers, forces the send file to be in that format.